# "Open folder" vs "Open the folder"

Tags: grammar, articles

Let's say someone is saying to somebody:

> "Open **the** folder C:\Documents"

Do we need 'the'-article here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

In general use you would need the *the* ("Open the book *Gone with the Wind*"; "Watch the film *Gone with the Wind*"; "Play the overture *The Hebrides*").

But in the computer world it is common to refer to objects with their classifier or type as a sort of extended name. So "Open the folder C:\Documents" is fine (and conforms with ordinary use) but "Open folder C:\Documents" is also in common use, treating "folder C:\Documents" as a sort of name.

Comment: I disagree with this. I work with computers for a living and, while "open folder C:\Documents" would be perfectly understood (as leaving out articles generally is), it sounds strange. If anything, if not "open the folder", it should just be "open C:\Documents".

Comment: I also want to ask about the titles mentioned. Can we say "Open the "Gone with the Wind"", "Have you watched the "Gone with the Wind""?

Comment: @embedc: No. The only time we use the article with proper names is in the (fairly unusual) case where we are qualifying it to distinguish different versions: "Do you mean the 1960 _Ocean's Eleven_ or the 2001 one?"